# NLP Lemmatizer removes 's' from 'us'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, lemmatization

I'm trying to use the following lemmatize function, but when inputting text with "us", the function removes the "s". How to prevent that?

```
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
w_tokenizer = TweetTokenizer()
def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)) for w in \
                                     w_tokenizer.tokenize((text))]
lemmatize_text('us')
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to exclude short word (eg less than 4 letters long) from the lemmatisation. Or 5, as you don't want the _-ing_ removed from _sing_ or _king_.

Comment: @OliverMason `lemmatized_output = ' '.join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in \
                                     w_tokenizer.tokenize((text)) if len(w) >4 )`  , this is what I added to the code, but the function removes words that have less than 4 letters. How do I make it just skip instead of removing completely?

Comment: You need to iterate over the tokenised text, and add the word or the lemmatised version if length > 4. That's a Python issue, not an NLP one, I'm afraid.